# MinGW compiled executable with networking won't run on x64 systems

Tags: c++, mingw, cross-compiling, 32bit-64bit, winsock

I have written an application in C/C++ using windows sockets and I link it with -lws2_32 while compiling with MinGW. I compile on Windows (I have tried both x32 and x64 VMs). The problem is that while the executable runs if I run it on a x32 machine (I tried a Windows XP machine) it gets stuck in networking if run from a x64 VM without the MinGW installation.

I tried to compile witch static, static g++ and static libc and nothing really works. It's a program with a UDP client and a TCP server. Windows ask for firewall permissions but the packets are never sent (I run wireshark just to be sure).

Am I doing something wrong with the compilation? I am new to windows programming and cross compiling.

Comment: I think you should paste some example how you use the sockets. Without code it is hard to say what you do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved my problem. The problem was that the VMs had npcap installed with Wireshark which created a loopback virtual nic. For some reason the program did not work while this interface was connected.

The packet sent was a UDP broadcast packet.